# How to embed schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to embed a category schema inside the product schema which effectively would just be the Object ID and title.

My category model:

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255
  }
});

const Category = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);

module.exports.categorySchema = categorySchema;
module.exports = Category;
```

Product model:

```
const { categorySchema } = require("./categoryModel");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlenth: 255
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: 0
  },
  category: {
    type: categorySchema,
    required: true
  },
});

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);

module.exports = Product;
```

The error I am getting in console is:

> TypeError Invalid value for schema path `category.type`

If I console.log() out categorySchema I get the following:

```
Schema {
  obj: {
    name: {
      type: [Function: String],
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 255
    }
  },
  paths: {
    name: SchemaString {
      enumValues: [],
      regExp: null,
      path: 'name',
      instance: 'String',
      validators: [Array],
      getters: [],
      setters: [],
      options: [Object],
      _index: null,
      isRequired: true,
      requiredValidator: [Function],
      originalRequiredValue: true,
      minlengthValidator: [Function],
      maxlengthValidator: [Function],
      [Symbol(mongoose#schemaType)]: true
    },
```

Comment: I'm afraid you cant do that

Comment: @mandaputtra, I actually did in in another project following a tutorial and it worked but for some reason is not working in a new project I am doing. I checked the npm packages and don't see anything obvious. So I don't think it required a dependency in order to have made it work

Comment: Interesting, maybe you could add `new Schema(categorySchema)`?

Comment: i think there is some problem with your export. You are not properly exporting the category schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
category: {
    type: categorySchema,
    required: true
}
```

use

```
category : categorySchema
```

Also, it looks like there is a mistake in your export.

Try changing it to this :

```
module.exports = {
    Category : Category,
    categorySchema : categorySchema
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I get the following error now: `TypeError Invalid value for schema path 'category'`

Comment: can you see if you are exporting the categorySchema correctly? Try `console.log(categorySchema)` and show me the results

Comment: I tried to paste all the code in but Stack overflow moaned that my post was mostly code and wouldn't let me save. I have added the first bit to my original question for you to look at

Comment: whats your mongoose version?

Comment: Mongoose version is  5.5.12

Comment: if there is just one field, why are you creating a separate Schema?

Comment: I like to keep everything separated, just feels cleaner to me.

Comment: Did the solution work? There was some error in your exports, did you try the solution? I had updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, only saw it now. Seems to work as far as I can tell. Thanks!